# Xrdp session has wrong display screen size and aspect ratio

Tags: linux, x11, display, vnc, xrdp

I am using remote desktop on a windows machine to connect to a CentOS 7 machine running a Xrdp server. Recently I had a problem with an application, where the avaialable openGL version (2.1) was not enough and it suggested either updating it, or using VNC.

While trying to make a VNC connection to work I made several updates inlcuding a Kernel update. I could not get the turboVNC to work at the same time than Xrdp, and damaged the settings somehow.

Now, when I connect to the Xrdp session the Gnome shell window is very small and has a weird aspect ratio, making it unusable (see picture below, the black area is the the size of my screen). Even if logged out of the gnome session, where I am able to select other shell (KDE, for example) I still have the same window size.
[image]

Since I could not find a similar problem, I am not sure what is causing the problem.
How could I return the size of the window to its original shape and size?

Comment: The first place you should be looking is the default.rdp file on you MS-Windows client.

Comment: I do not think it has something to do with the MS-Windows client. I also have access to another workstation where I do not have this problem. Since I am using a ssh-tunel and connecting to localhost:port, I do not need to change the configurations in the remote desktop, so that the same setting applies for both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7.9 target- same issue but with Mate GUI.  Restarting the xrdp service on the target worked for me.